# Match data in one spreadsheet against another

Tags: excel-formula

Eg sheetA And sheetB have same info below:

Ref1 USD100 12dec2016
Ref2 EUR300 11nov2015
Ref3 SGD500 30oct2016
Ref4 USD400 29feb2016

What is the simplest way to match and ensure both sheets info Matched and highlight the unmatched item?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In sheetA in column D (starting with the one shown in cell D2) you can use the following formula:

```
D2 =AND(VLOOKUP($A2,sheetB!$A:$C,2,FALSE)=B2,VLOOKUP($A2,sheetB!$A:$C,3,FALSE)=C2)
```

This will provide a TRUE or FALSE output in the case where the info from columns B and C match or don't between same references on both sheets. Regards,